# Mixing CocoaPods, SPM and Multiple targets

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I have an `Xcode` project, consisting of multiple `swift packages`, some `cocoa pods` and one `target dependency`.
In workspace I have:

- Project `UltronSDK` - xcode project of type `Framework`. This project contains some `SPM` dependencies
- Project `UltronApp` - Xcode project of type `iOS Application`. This is the main application, and it should include `UltronSDK` as a `framework`
- Few swift packages, that are imported in `UltronSDK`
- Global workspace for all these things above.

When I try to compile the main application, Im seeing errors like:

```
Could not build Objective-C module 'UltronSDK'
Module `FindloSDK` not found
```

`FindloSDK` is a `Swift Package` imported inside `UltronSDK`. If I select `UltronSDK` itself as a target during compilation, it compiles correctly. Problem occurs only when I try to compile `UltronApp`, which should import `UltronSDK`.

This is how my `Podfile` looks

```
use_frameworks!
workspace 'UltronAR'

project 'UltronApp'
project 'UltronSDK'

target 'UltronApp' do
    project 'UltronApp/UltronApp'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end

target 'UltronSDK' do
    project 'UltronSDK/UltronSDK'
    pod 'GoogleMLKit/ObjectDetection'
    pod 'GoogleMLKit/ObjectDetectionCustom'
    pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift'
    pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift/Metal'
    pod 'TensorFlowLiteSwift/CoreML'
end
```

I can't figure it out. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: did you try delete the derived data or pod update ?

Comment: @zeytin yes, tried multiple times. Didnt help

Comment: ever try disabled Find Implicit Dependencies still no :) ?

Comment: It's enabled, but doesn't help

Comment: make it disable and try again pls

Comment: Still the same issue. I disabled it in both UltronApp and UltronSDK

Comment: Oh, sorry, different issue - now I get No Such module UltronSDK. I will try to solve it

Comment: did you solve hopefully you did and I wonder how it is :)